# Rest with oauth2

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I'm using [this library](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/securing-your-api-with-oauth-2/) with my codeigniter rest service. Basically, I have a REST_controller, that is inherited, and checks for a valid token, using that library.

All I want is to provide an API to secure some of the API methods. 
Now, I'm lost reading most of the specs for oauth2 and tutorials regarding that library.

Can anyone help me, proving good tutorials, examples and explanations on I can achieve, a simple login system and then, call user authenticated methods.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have implemented the same library which you have mentioned and got it working successfully.
If you tell me what error you are getting I can help in fixing the problem for you.

Comment: @s1d I hope you don't mind sharing a demo/source-code of what you made with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I did this for work so do not have an open source version. Will take some effort to make it into open sourced. I'm open to help if you are encountering any difficulties with your implementation though.

Answer (score 5):

Just constructed a pictorial tutorial for OAuth2.0 specs. In case you may find this useful:

Tutorial : http://restful-fundamentals.blogspot.in/2013/04/oauth-20-introducation.html

Also adding a web app demo demostrating the different Authorisation Grants flows. It contains the path to the google code as well as some other tips.
http://restful-fundamentals.blogspot.in/2013/04/svn-repository-oauth20-spectifications.html

***Your comments at that blog may be useful to me to improve the contents there*

Answer (score 1):

I did a demo using spring MVC and spring security you can find [source code here](https://github.com/bassemZohdy/Spring_REST_OAuth_Demo)